# Symfony 2 file upload: guessExtension() doesn't work for .docx files

Tags: symfony

```
public function preUpload()
{
    if (null !== $this->file) {
        $this->path = $this->file->guessExtension();

    }
}
```

This doesn't work for .docx files.

I get a file stored under the name "myfile." -> no extension.

How to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
 getExtension()
```

as a fallback?

[Symfony API](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.html#method_getExtension)

Comment: Symfony class "File" extends PHP's "SplFileInfo"
\SplFileInfo::getExtension() is not available before PHP 5.3.6

Answer (score 13):

I think you must use:

getClientOriginalExtension()

because you want to get the extension of the original name not the temporary name that the file has in your server.

http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html

Answer (score 1):

I found a bug in symfony core files where It was missing a mimeType for the .xls files.

We had the same behaviour: GuessExtension would return null.

My team and I narrowed it down to an array which lists symfony's mime types.

Here is a link to the same solution I answered on another question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36435844/3980097

You will find the exact path to MimeTypeExtensionGuesse.php

In your case, the missing mime Type might be:

```
'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' => 'docx',
```

I hope this helps!