# Symfony2 guessExtension() return invalid extension of .docx file?

Tags: php, symfony, mime-types

I found similar questions like [Symfony 2 file upload: guessExtension() doesn't work for .docx files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556150/symfony-2-file-upload-guessextension-doesnt-work-for-docx-files)  but not found any appropriate answer so that I am  repeating this question.

I am using **Symfony 2.3.18** & **PHP 5.4.17**  but `$this->getFile()->guessExtension()`
 return "*zip*" extension for "*docx*" file. and I also used `$this->getFile()->getExtension()` which returns " " (empty).

Comment: The mime type returned for a docx file may well be zip, because it is a zipped collection of xml files, so has a zip signature.... similarly with xlsx or pptx files

Comment: @MarkBaker is right. [It is a zipped file format](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docx)

Comment: I know It is zip collection of xml files,But what to do if I want to get proper extension i.e. docx in my case . Any idea @MarkBaker ?

Comment: You modify the browser that's done the upload to send a correct mime type; or you modify mime magic to read a correct signature.... this is basically something outside of PHP control

Comment: hi @MarkBaker, I have used `$file->getClientOriginalExtension();` , Is it safe way to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used another function as follow to get proper extension which is not recommended but workaround.

```
$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
```