# Symfony2 UploadedFile::guessExtension() for XML

Tags: xml, symfony, file-upload, mime-types

I'm having a problem getting extension for uploaded XML files. Tried `getExtension()` (returns empty string), `guessExtension()` and `guessClientExtension()` (both returns `NULL`).

Should I just hardcode extension (I know it should always be XML) or is there a way to get it? I see mimeType of the uploaded file is `text/xml`. When I upload .txt file, it gets extension right.

Maybe I'm getting uploaded file wrong?

```
$request = $this->getRequest();

$form = $this->createForm(new FileImportType(), null, ['em' => $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()]);
$form->submit($request);
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $file = null; // @var $file \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile
    foreach ($request->files as $file) {
        $file = $file['file'];
        break;
    }
    var_dump($file->guessExdtension());
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try to get it from the uploaded $file->getFilename()
Then you can extract the extension using:

```
 $fileExtension = pathinfo( $file->getFilename(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

In the php docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Comment: That's one way. If nobody posts a better solution, i think I'll go with this one. **Edit:** Tried it, but `getFilename()` returns me some semi-random string `phpxxxxxx` where _xxxxxx_ is random alphanumerics. Maybe I'm getting uploaded file wrong. Will edit my question.

Comment: Try $file->getClientOriginalName() 
http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html

Answer (score 1):

Don't edit the file directly in the vendor dir (do a pull request if need be) as when upgrading you'll lose your changes.

But use `$file->getClientOriginalName()` to get the original file name that you have uploaded `if $file->guessExtension()` gets you the wrong one.

I had similar problem with mp3's being recognised as mpga's

Answer (score 0):

I've working working hard with my team to find a solution to this problem.

It seems like Symfony's library is missing a mimeType in it's core files.

You can add the mime type in:

```
../vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/MineType/MimeTypeExtensionGuesser.php
```

In my case guessExtension() couldn't recognize .xls files.

It was missing the mime type: "application/vnd.ms-office"

So I added this line to the $defaultExtensions array in MimeTypeExtensionGuess.php :

```
'application/vnd.ms-office' => 'xls',
```

In your case it might be missing:

```
'application/xml' => 'xml',
```

Cheers! I hope this helps.